# Change PIN of a Gemalto Smartcard through a script

Tags: smartcard, gemalto

We have to use the Gemalto IDPrime .Net card Smartcard. We get these USB Dongles and have to change the PIN.

Gemalto says via windows:

> ```
> From the Start menu, choose Run and type PINTool.
> Insert a IDPrime .Net card in the reader as prompted, and click OK. The change PIN interface appears
> Enter the old PIN (the default PIN value is 0000), the new PIN and confirm the new PIN.
> Click on Change Pin
> ```
>
> http://support.gemalto.com/index.php?id=how_to_change_pin_in_a_idprime#.VWYTWUa8rV8

This works, but I want to set a new PIN/password via powershell or c#, i. e. under control of a program. 
How to do that or is impossible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to change PIN via unmanaged PKCS#11 API that can be easily accessed from C# with a managed .NET wrapper called [Pkcs11Interop](http://pkcs11interop.net/) which I am the author of.

Here is the code sample that may help you get started:

```cs
using Net.Pkcs11Interop.Common;
using Net.Pkcs11Interop.HighLevelAPI;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Load PKCS#11 library provided by Gemalto
            using (Pkcs11 pkcs11 = new Pkcs11("gtop11dotnet.dll", true))
            {
                // Find first slot/reader with token/card present
                Slot slot = pkcs11.GetSlotList(true)[0];

                // Open RW session
                using (Session session = slot.OpenSession(false))
                {
                    // Login as normal user with current PIN
                    session.Login(CKU.CKU_USER, "0000");

                    // Set the new pin for the logged in user
                    session.SetPin("0000", "1111");

                    session.Logout();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Looks good. 
But i can't get it to work. 
GetSlotList Returns the usb stick - but OpenSession Returns CKR_GENERAL_ERROR.

Comment: i get two Slots - i have a dell Keyboard with Smartcard and the gemalto usb dongle. i use the right one (in my case second one). 
is it possible that don't have the right gtop11dotnet.dll ?

Comment: AFAIK gtop11dotnet.dll was bundled in an older IDGo 500 middleware package and there is IDPrimePKCS11.dll available in a newer [IDGo 800](http://www.gemalto.com/products/idgo_800_generic/index.html) middleware package. Sadly IDGo 800 cannot be downloaded directly from Gemalto site but I believe you should be able to get it from your card supplier.

Comment: @Dominik I forgot to mention that CKR_GENERAL_ERROR returned by gtop11dotnet.dll can mean literally anything as it is the most generic error code defined in PKCS#11 specification.

Comment: Thank you very much. that's it. I've used the wrong dll. Not it works as expected :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer @jariq posted for C# I was able to get the following to work in `PowerShell` for changing the `Admin PIN`.

> **Note:** this is specifically for Gemalto IDPrime .NET cards which are being replaced by the IDPrime MD product line. See the end of this post for more info.

```
# www.pkcs11interop.net
Add-Type -Path "C:\Somepath\Pkcs11Interop.4.0.0\lib\net45\Pkcs11Interop.dll"

# Gemalto PKCS11 driver
# 1 = single threaded
$pkcs11 = New-Object Net.Pkcs11Interop.HighLevelAPI.Pkcs11("C:\somepath\gtop11dotnet64.dll",1)

# 0 = SlotsType.WithTokenPresent
$slots = $pkcs11.GetSlotList(0)

$slot = $slots[0] # often its the first

# create session
# 1 = SessionType.ReadWrite
$session = $slot.OpenSession(1)

[byte[]]$defaultPIN = 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00

# 000000000000000000000001
[byte[]]$newPIN = 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x31

# 0 = Security Officer a.k.a. Admin
$session.Login(0, $defaultPIN)

$session.SetPin($defaultPIN, $newPIN)

$session.Dispose()
$slot.CloseAllSessions()
$pkcs11.Dispose()
```

I found the most success converting each `PIN` to a byte array for use with logging in and changing the `PIN`. To convert the 48 digit Admin PIN to 24 bytes, the following function was created.

```
Function Convert-AdminPinToByteArray([Validatepattern("^[0-9A-F]{48}$")][string]$AdminPIN)
{
    $ReturnByte = New-Object byte[] 24

    $n = 0

    for($i=0;$i -lt $ReturnByte.Length;$i++)
    {
        $ReturnByte[$i] = [byte]"0x$($AdminPIN.SubString($n,2))"
        $n = $n + 2
    }

    return $ReturnByte

} # End Function Convert-AdminPinToByteArray
```

## Gemalto Card Types

The above examples are based off **Gemalto IDPrime .NET** cards which are being retired. The [End of Sale (EOS) announcement is here](http://data-protection-updates.gemalto.com/2016/07/31/idprime-net-smart-card-family-end-of-sales-eos-announcement/).

> ```
> IDPrime .Net
> IDPrime .Net Bio
>
> Key Dates: 
> Milestone                  Date
> Last-Time-Buy (LTB)        September 29, 2017
> End-of-Sale (EOS)          September 30, 2017
> End-of-Life (EOL)          September 30, 2018
> ```

#### Replacement

[Per the EOS announcement PDF](http://data-protection-updates.safenet-inc.com/files/2016/07/Dot-net-EOS-announcement-July-31-2016.pdf):

> Products Gemalto’s family of IDPrime .NET 510/511 smart cards will be replaced by the **IDPrime MD 83x** and **IDPrime MD 84x** series of smart cards.

#### Programming the Replacement cards

I've included the information about distinguishing card types because I have a  Gemalto IDPrime MD 830 for testing and the above techniques do not work. In fact, the card doesn't even show as being present in the reader using the above techniques.